# What css styling to achieve to ensure Highchart fits within the outer container and resizes on window resize (i.e. they are responsive)

Tags: html, css, angular, highcharts, window-resize

**Context**:
I am trying to create 3 charts on 1 row (each has a minimum width) such that on window resize, the charts should also resize and may go to next row depending on the browser total width.

**Problem**:
Currently, I am missing something in the css because the chart is overflowing within the demo container below. The tooltip looks fine, but only half of the chart is seen in the container and both the axes are also hidden.

*Has someone implemented something similar before? I want to understand how to load the charts in the div.*

P.S. In the code below, highcharts-container is the inbuilt div which contains the charts. I am using the latest version of Highcharts and Angular 7.

**My current html code -->**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md4 demo>
   <div class="demo-container">
   <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="options1" [callbackFunction]="cb1"> 
   </highcharts-chart>
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md4 demo>
   <div class="demo-container">
   <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="options2" [callbackFunction]="cb2"> 
   </highcharts-chart>
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md4 demo>
   <div class="demo-container">
   <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="options3" [callbackFunction]="cb3"> 
   </highcharts-chart>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**My css code (The main part) -->**

```
.container-fluid{
width:100%
}
.demo{
margin: 20px 0;
min-width: 448px;
}
.demo-container{
position: relative;
border: 1px solid transparent;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1793f5;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.highcharts-container{
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: can you post a picture? to hide overflow use, overflow: hidden;

Comment: I cannot post a picture as it is my company code of conduct. Sorry! Basically, the chart is overflown (hidden) and if I use overflow:auto, it still doesn't work.

Comment: okay, i see! are you able to construct a mockup? i am having a hard time understanding the problem and i recon other people do aswell. I will mention that in your html code pasted here you do have 3 too many division endings

Comment: Makes sense. I will make one and upload by tomorrow. Thank you so much for looking into this.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with a sample data which I could work on?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wftxkw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts 
I have tried my best to create a mockup. The charts overflow its container. I have also used the bootstrap layout to be able to see 3 charts in a row if the screen is big enough. If the screen is not bg enough, the charts can go to next row. Also, on resize of window, the highcharts should resize upto its minimum width.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to include the following CSS as a part of `demo-container` or `container-fluid`... one of it should do the deal for you.

```css
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

one of the harder challenges i have encountered, but add this to the style.css
and you have your contents dynamic inside its container.

```
.highcharts-background, .highcharts-root, .highcharts-container {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

---

### is this what you are looking for?

[image: image description]

This was made using images of the graphs in the links you posted. I also used flexboxes which seems to be what you are looking for.

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container-fluid div {
  width: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;

  min-width: 33%;
}

.container-fluid{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
border: 2px solid blue;

justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="chartOne">
    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/161954d0841b7a398d5f0d63e1b2bcc4.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="chartOne">
    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/161954d0841b7a398d5f0d63e1b2bcc4.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="chartOne">
    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/161954d0841b7a398d5f0d63e1b2bcc4.png" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @MaitriVasa i see, let me try to work on it in the stackbiz you posted

Comment: @MaitriVasa there is soo much css and html in this document and its close to impossible to overwrite anything. i have gotten close to a solution, i could give you this and you'd have to figure out the rest with js or the html and css would need to be cleaned up 

https://i.gyazo.com/c8a446de354806e774d00c2e69e22435.mp4

Comment: Finally figured it out!

Comment: The video - that's exactly what I was looking for --> 1. The graphs go to next line on window resize 2. The graphs are not hidden and flow to its container

Comment: Do you have your code demo link where you made the changes?

Comment: @MaitriVasa in the video the size of the graph is 70% and does not scale well. The code i posted in the answer changes the parents divisions. There are like 5 containers and wrappers in the code which makes it incredibly hard to identify the correct divisions to target

Comment: @MaitriVasa can i contact you somewhere? the code with the explanation is a little extensive

Comment: Hi, the divs and containers are not important. It is for aesthetic pirposes only. The main goal is to have responsive highcharts. Hence, we can simplify the structure.

Comment: Hmm. I went into the dource code of the webpage do dig out the divs and containers. The problem in the link you posted was that out of the 5 containers, 3 were overflowing and 1 was not positioned nor sized accordingly. If the divs are not important then my first example should be sufficient with the right hierarchy of html

Comment: Hangouts --> maitrivasa15@gmail.com
Skype --> maitrivasa15

Comment: @MaitriVasa thank you, i will contact you tomorrow as it is 10 am here in norway and i am in bed!

Comment: I just need to see the right hierarchy of html with highcharts in it. I tried your posted code but the charts don't resize when I shrink the window; it instead produces a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Okay, sure. Thank you so much! I work in EST timezone (NewYork)

Comment: @MaitriVasa try adding display flex to the container surrounding the highcharts. I went into dev tools and used the select tool to find the hidden divisions

Comment: I can still see the scrollbar. Lets talk tomorrow

Comment: @MaitriVasa i have sent you an invite to a hangout later today